# iOS cookie setting issue: safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, cookies, mobile-safari

I am debugging a cookie setting issue which reproduces in both Chrome and Safari on iOS only. Behold the following code block that works fine on Chrome/Safari/Firefox on OSX:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') > -1) {
    window.onpagehide = placeCookie
} else {
    window.onbeforeunload = placeCookie
}

function placeCookie () {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {

        var cookie = 'cookieName=' + token + '; max-age=60'

        if (env === 'prod') {
            cookie += '; secure'
        }

        document.cookie = cookie
    }
}
```

This code is meant to place a cookie when the window detects navigation. In our case, because it's angularjs, we're listening for a page reload, and we want that cookie to go with the request.

Reload Code: `window.location.reload(true)`

To develop I'm using Charles Proxy to sniff the cookie, and also inspecting the cookies on a node server, because the safari inspector closes on page reload. When I reopen the inspector window, I can see the cookie is set in the browser, but neither the server or Charles sees the cookie. Here's a paste of the cookie from the safari inspector on iPad (which is not seen by server/charlesproxy):

```
Name        Value   Domain                      Path Expires 
cookieName  token   localhost.charlesproxy.com  /    7/10/2017, 11:23:13 PM 39
```

When I step through it on other browsers, the cookie is visible everywhere.

Does anyone know of any reason why iOS does not acknowledge the cookie? Is it possible the request is made on iOS before the cookie is placed?

Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to set the cookie right before they navigate to a different page and the cookie isn't being sent on the next page request?

Comment: It's a page reload that we're listening for, because it is a SPA, but other than that you're correct.

Comment: How are you reloading the page?

Comment: window.location.reload(true)

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
function setCookie(name, value, days = 7, path = '/') {
            const expires = new Date(Date.now() + days * 864e5).toUTCString()
            document.cookie = name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '; expires=' + expires + '; path=' + path
        }

setCookie('cookieName', accessToken, 1);
```

which works on all devices/browsers (as far as I know - not every combo tested, but certainly on iPhone/Mac with Chrome/Safari and PC with Chrome.) to set/keep the cookie.

It isn't significantly different than the code you show (for basic cookie creation) and may still not hit for the use you have, but might be worth a try....

Here's the getCookie side (I didn't write this code - picked it up somewhere - off SO most likely! - I just know it works great! :)

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
            if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
                c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
                if (c_start !== -1) {
                    c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
                    c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                    if (c_end === -1) {
                        c_end = document.cookie.length;
                    }
                    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```